# htaccess RewriteRule two scripts

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Good day!
I have two scripts in my root folder:

```
/index.php
/home.php
```

Both of them receive get parameter and display different pages, f.ex:

```
index.php?page=info
home.php?page=about
```

1) When I try to do clean URI by this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 #working ok
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 #doesn't load css,js
```

I found three advices: rather apply path of css,js folders to htaccess, use tag  or use absolute path.
I'm wondering are there any other ways to make it solely by htaccess. Or is it possible to change query string the way to remove "/" if there is one f.ex:
I insert

```
example.org/info/
```

And my string automatically becomes

```
example.org/info
```

2) My htaccess only works with index.php. How should I change my rule to work with home.php if there is "userhome" in query string to make such queries possible:

```
example.org/home/about
```

P.S

```
RewriteRule ^home/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ home.php?page=$1
```

Working the way I need, concerning my second question. However I haven't still done with the problem of css, js loading. Any tips please

Comment: Ok I think your requirements are changing a bit. what exactly is "userhome" and where does that fit in your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle CSS not loading is to use `<base>` tag. That way you can use relative URL's and it won't break anything with your rules.

This will go in the `head` section of your site..

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/" />
```

You can try these rules for your your requirements.

```
#Redirect to home.php
RewriteRule ^home/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ home.php?page=$1 [L]
#Remove the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#Redirect to index.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is working great, thank you. Howeer I still have some issues, conserning the second part. I did some edits, so I could confuse you. So, actually. I need to rewrite the following URI: "example.org/home/about" to: example.org/home.php?page=about. And besides make js, css working.

Comment: I edited the rules based on your updated home link in the question. This should work for your rules.